# error - Multiple Regression OLS class

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I having problem to adjust with ols class the equation
*y = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>x<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup>*

The code:

```
xs = numpy.loadtxt('teste.csv', skiprows=1, dtype=float, delimiter=';', 
     usecols=(0,1))

y = log(xs[:,0])
x = 1/xs[:,1]
x2 = (1/xs[:,1])**2

mymodel = ols.ols(y,x,'y',['x1', 'x2'])
mymodel.summary()`
```

I got this error:

```
print '''% -5s          % -5.6f     % -5.6f     % -5.6f     % -5.6f''' % tuple([self.x_varnm[i],self.b[i],self.se[i],self.t[i],self.p[i]])
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your `x` as:

```
x = 1/xs[:,1:2] # slice to keep (n, 1) shape
x2 = (1/xs[:,1:2])**2
x = np.hstack((x, x2))
```

You are telling `ols` to expect a two column matrix for `x`, but are passing a single one in, hence the error.

Comment: or `x = 1/xs[:,1,np.newaxis]` which looks less like a mistake to me.  `x[1:2]` is the kind of thing I'll go back and change in old code :P